# new build issues in azure pipeline windows

Tags: c++, cmake, azure-pipelines

I have a C++ project which is built with Visual Studio 2019. I started to get strange build errors in Azure Pipeline in December. Before then, the build test had passed all the time. The build is still fine on my Windows machines. It has issues only in Azure Pipeline. I get this error

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include\memory(619,23): error C3861: '__iso_volatile_load32': identifier not found [D:\a\1\s\build\ode\raisimODE.vcxproj]
```

The error message seems like it is looking for ARM instructions. Here is a snippet of my build script

```
  cd $(Build.Repository.LocalPath)
  mkdir build
  cd build
  cmake -Q .. -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -A x64 -DRAISIM_TEST=ON -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=$(Pipeline.Workspace)\dep\raisim_env
  cmake --build . --config Release
  ctest -VV -C Release
  cd $(Build.Repository.LocalPath)
```

Comment: Looking at `\memory(619,23)` `__iso_volatile_load32` is only used if `_M_CEE_PURE` is defined and _"..._M_CEE_PURE __Deprecated__ beginning in Visual Studio 2015. Defined as 001 if the __/clr:pure__ compiler option is set. Otherwise, undefined. ..."_  see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/predefined-macros?view=msvc-160

Comment: I don't use /clr:pure option. Could this be set as default in Azure Pipeline? How can I avoid it?

Comment: @RichardCritten must read "is only used if `_M_CEE_PURE` is *not* defined"

Comment: I am getting more confused. If it is deprecated, then it shouldn't be used. So did I do wrong?

Comment: What's that `-Q` option you pass to cmake?

Comment: @fabian I copy-pasted that line from somewhere. I removed `-Q` but still gets the same error